# `ZIPPO_CONTEXT_INVALID` error when querying 0x goerli swap api quote endpoint

Tags: blockchain, 0x, decentralized-exchange

When querying the following endpoint and parameters: https://goerli.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&sellAmount=1000000000000&sellToken=0x88D96a012a71f053041fe2BF27bC4703cebBB7b2

I get error like this:

```
 {
    "code": 100,
    "reason": "Validation Failed",
    "validationErrors": [
        {
            "field": "zippo",
            "code": 1010,
            "reason": "ZIPPO_CONTEXT_INVALID",
            "description": "Invalid zippo context"
        }
    ]
}
```

This endpoint is that I used before with the same params and it had worked well before.
just I got the error from yesterday.
I tested Mumbai endpoint too but it also returns the same error now.

Any help in understanding what is causing the issue would be helpful.

Comment: Same issue here. It worked yesterday but today (same code) it started giving this weird error. Maybe it's a Goerli endpoint issue?

Comment: Same issue, suddenly stopped working on testnets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x team here. The ZIPPO error on goerli has been fixed! Thank you for your patience

Remember to use your API key in the header. Ex:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://goerli.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&sellAmount=1000000000000&sellToken=0x88D96a012a71f053041fe2BF27bC4703cebBB7b2' --header '0x-api-key: <insert-your-key>'
```

Comment: Thanks for fix.
How about mumbai?
I got the same error on mumbai as well.
goerli api looks work well actually.

Comment: As of 8/22, Mumbai should be fixed now as well